# SPI Loopback value received is half of transmitted value

Tags: microcontroller, pic, spi, loopback

I am testing SPI of my PIC24E512GU814 microcontroller. In order to test, I connected MOSI to MISO.

I wrote the following code for SPI initialization:

```
SPI3CON1 = 0; 
SPI3CON1bits.CKE = 1;
SPI3CON1bits.SPRE = 7;
SPI3CON1bits.PPRE = 3;
SPI3CON1bits.MSTEN = 1;
SPI3STATbits.SPIEN = 1;
```

Then for transmitting/receiving the following code:

```
SPI3_ENABLE = 0;  //chip select
delayUs(1);
while (SPI3STATbits.SPITBF);
SPI3BUF = test;
while (!SPI3STATbits.SPIRBF)
{
      if (--timeout == 0)
      {
          debugOutput(0, "\r\nTimeout SPI 3\r\n");
      }
}
temp = SPI3BUF;
debugOutput(0, "\r\nValue read on SPI 3 Port:%d\r\n", temp);
SPI3_ENABLE = 1;
```

I am always getting half the value transmitted. For example if I transmit 54, I am reading 27 in the receive buffer. What can be the issue?

Modified the code to the following didn't help

```
delayUs(1);
//writeSPI(eSpiPort3, &test, sizeof(byte));
debugOutput(0, "\r\nWriting on SPI 3 Port:%d\r\n", test);
SPI3_ENABLE = 0;
while (SPI3STATbits.SPITBF);
SPI3BUF = test;
while (!SPI3STATbits.SPIRBF)
{
    if (--timeout == 0)
    {
        debugOutput(0, "\r\nTimeout SPI 3\r\n");
    }
}
temp = SPI3BUF;
SPI3_ENABLE = 1;
delayUs(1);   
debugOutput(0, "\r\nValue read on SPI 3 Port:%d\r\n", temp);
```

Comment: 54 in binary is 110110,27 is 11011, the last bit seems to get lost have you seen the waveforms of MOSI and MISO on an Oscilloscope or Logicanalyzer?
Try enabling the CS before the debugOutput call, and try disabling the delayUs in the beginning and observe the data waveforms.

Comment: I have updated the code after making modifications. Still no help. The value received is half. I have to try Logic Analyzer. I have buspirate. But it will not work as it doesn't support slave mode

Comment: This sort of problem usually happens because the mode or capture edge is incorrect; what is your port setup?

Comment: Pin Configuration is correct.   SDO3 is output, SDI3 is input , SCK3 is output and SS3 is output

Comment: @md.jamal You have set PPRE and SPRE to 1:1, 
This is from the reference manual :
Do not set the primary and secondary prescalers to the value of 1:1 at the same time. Page 9 http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/70005185a.pdf

Comment: Commenting the line which set SPRE did the job. Now I am getting the same value which I am transmitting in loopback.. Thanks. I can accept it as answer if you post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have set PPRE bits and SPRE bits in SSPI3CON1 register to 1:1, This is from the  Page 9 of the [reference manual](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/70005185a.pdf)

> Do not set the primary and secondary prescalers to the value of 1:1
>   at the same time.